# OpenOffice Calc macro in Python - macro triggered by a click of a button, how to get a name of that button?

Tags: macros, openoffice, openoffice-calc

I am really new to this and OpenOffice Developer's Guide is too difficult for me to understand or I'd help myself.

I have a large number of rows with data and in each row I want a button that would trigger a particular macro `rowMacro`. That macro will analyze/modify data in that particular row. For simplicity, let's say it it just writes an arbitrary string somewhere in the row:

```
import uno
oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()

def rowMacro(*args):
  oSheet = oDoc.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
  oCell1 = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A4")
  CurContr=oDoc.getCurrentController().getSelection()
  oCell1.String = "Tada!"
```

I don't want to create a dozen of separate near-identical scripts for each row - so no `rowMacroRowA` triggered by a specific button in row A, etc. I'd rather have a number of buttons all triggering the same python macro. That macro somehow needs to determine which button was used (each button has a unique name) and modify only the appropriate row. So I need to figure out the way to get a button name in python (I'll know how to handle it from there).

I stumbled upon a [webpage](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html) with an excerpt like this:

```
# get the sheet
accueil_sheet = model.Sheets.getByName("Accueil")
# access the draw page
oDrawPage = accueil_sheet.DrawPage
# count the number of form
oDrawPage.getForms().getCount()
# get the list box of the control element
ListBox = oDrawPage.getForms().getByIndex(0).getByName("Listbox")
# get the list box item list
ListBox.StringItemList
# get the list box controller
ListBoxCtrl = model.getCurrentController().getControl(ListBox)
# get the selected items:
ListBoxCtrl.SelectedItems
```

but I do not know how to deduct my problem's solution from that.

To summarize:

1. How to get a name of a button that was used to trigger a macro?
2. Better yet - how to get its position, in particular a row? (this one I'd rather figure out on my own if you push me in the right direction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button name can be determined from the [ActionEvent](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/ActionEvent.html) that gets passed as a parameter.  For the example below, I named the button `btnRow4`.

Getting the position is harder, but possible by obtaining the [XShape](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/drawing/XShape.html) of the button from the DrawPage.  Here is code that illustrates how all of this works:

```
def rowMacro(action_event=None):

    ## Get the button name.
    if action_event:
        button_name = action_event.Source.Model.getName()
    else:
        button_name = ''
    if button_name == 'btnRow4':
        rowname = "4"
    else:
        rowname = "5"

    ## Get the button position.
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oSheet = oDoc.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    oDrawPage = oSheet.DrawPage
    oShape = None
    for i in range(oDrawPage.Count):
        aShape = oDrawPage.getByIndex(i)
        if aShape.supportsService("com.sun.star.drawing.ControlShape"):
            if aShape.getControl().getName() == button_name:
                oShape = aShape
    if oShape:
        ypos = oShape.getPosition().Y
    else:
        ypos = "(didn't click on a button)"

    ## Show results.
    oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A" + rowname)
    oCell.String = "Y Position: " + str(ypos)
```

A discussion about `getPosition()` is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=82422.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a dozen. No follow-up needed, the example helped me a lot.